# How to set row values base on index levels in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a column to a `Pandas` dataframe and set values based on index levels 0 and 1. For example, set the value to `buy` for indexes where level 0 is `hom` and column `delta` is greater than 0. And set the value to `sell` for indexes where level 0 is `hom` and column `delta` is lower than 0. There are other rules for different value of level 0.

How can I do that ?

```
>df
         delta
fut ABC  15284.233222
pos DEF  0.248976
    POL  0.002041
    ABC  0.043585
hom YTY  0.054100
    MNN -0.356873
```

This is the desired output:

```
>df
         delta    new_col
fut ABC  15284.23 nan
pos DEF  0.248976 nan
    POL  0.002041 nan
    ABC  0.043585 nan
hom YTY  0.054100 buy
    MNN -0.356873 sell
```

I can filter the dataframe with `loc` for not sure how to create the new column.

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(level=0) == 'hom'] > 0

         delta    new_col
hom YTY  0.054100 True
    MNN -0.356873 False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to do any boolean masking since your data already has a usable index!
You can simply use `.loc` to subset and create a new column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.loc['hom', 'new_col'] = np.where(df.loc['hom', 'delta'] > 0, 'buy', 'sell')

print(df)
                delta new_col
fut ABC  15284.233222     NaN
pos DEF      0.248976     NaN
    POL      0.002041     NaN
    ABC      0.043585     NaN
hom YTY      0.054100     buy
    MNN     -0.356873    sell
```

Comment: One line solution, great.

Comment: Nice solution. Did you use np.where because [pd.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) only allows one value to be substituted (not both)?

Comment: That's exactly why I reached for `np.where` if `DataFrame.where` (or `Series.where`) could replace both then I would use that. 

If you're curious about a pure pandas alternative you can use `.map({True: 'buy', False: 'sell})` or `pd.Categorical.from_codes(bool_arr, ['sell', 'buy'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can access index values with `df.index.get_level_values`, then `np.where/select`, for example:

```
is_hom = df.index.get_level_values(level=0) == 'hom'

df['new_col'] = np.select((~is_hom, df.delta > 0), (np.nan, 'buy'), 'sell')
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks. For some reason it point a `SyntaxError` at the `!`. If I remove it there is no error but then the values are wrongly set

Comment: The `!` should probably be a `~` to flip the boolean array.

Answer (score 1):

To do conditional manipulations like that I would move the index values to the columns:

```python
df.index = df.index.rename(names=['a', 'b'])
df = df.reset_index()
df['new_col'] = None

# Assignments
df.loc[(df.a == 'hom') & (df.delta > 0), 'new_col'] = 'buy'
df.loc[(df.a == 'hom') & (df.delta < 0), 'new_col'] = 'sell'

# Reset index
df = df.set_index(['a', 'b'])
```

Result:

```
                delta new_col
a   b                        
fut ABC  15284.233222    None
pos DEF      0.248976    None
    POL      0.002041    None
    ABC      0.043585    None
hom YTY      0.054100     buy
    MNN     -0.356873    sell
```